# How to get UpsertData function to insert data into the data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, error-messages, upsert

On the landing page I have a form that is submitting and gathering all the RequestParameter values. When it gets to the UpsertData function it doesn't fire even the few values I have in the function to the data extension. Not sure why its not putting the data into the data extension. Thanks for any help. Let me know if you need any further code.

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1");
  HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST");
  HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  try {
</script>
<br><br>
%%[
  VAR @data_extension, @email, @firstName, @lastName, @phone, @company, @jobTitle, @city, @state, @zipCode, @fpAccountNumber, @fpNews, @fpTextAlerts, @createdDate, @srcCampaign, @srcLandingPage, @botCheck, @submit

  SET @data_extension = "Test_LP_GeneralForm_Display"

  SET @email = RequestParameter("Email Address")<br>
  SET @firstName = RequestParameter("First Name")<br>
  SET @lastName = RequestParameter("Last Name")<br>
  SET @phone = RequestParameter("Primary Phone")<br>
  SET @company = RequestParameter("Company")<br>
  SET @jobTitle = RequestParameter("Job Title")<br>
  SET @city = RequestParameter("City")<br>
  SET @state = RequestParameter("State")<br>
  SET @zipCode = RequestParameter("Zip Code")<br>
  SET @accountNumber = RequestParameter("Account Number")<br>
  SET @news = RequestParameter("Subscribe to News")<br>
  SET @textAlerts = RequestParameter("Subscribe to Text Alerts")<br>
  SET @createdDate = RequestParameter("Created Date")<br>
  SET @srcCampaign = RequestParameter("Source Campaign")<br>
  SET @srcLandingPage = RequestParameter("Source Landing Page")<br>
  SET @botCheck = RequestParameter("Bot Check")<br>
  SET @submit = RequestParameter("Submit")<br>
  
  
  UpsertData("@data_extension", 1, "Email Address", @email, "First Name", @firstName, "Last Name", @lastName) 

]%%
<br><br>
<script runat="server">
  } catch (e) {
    Variable.SetValue("errorMessage", Stringify(e.message) + Stringify(e.description));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure you have value in those var? I would suggest printing them to confirm

Comment: Yeah, I have printed all the variables and they come in on the landing page.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the quotes around your DE name.

```
UpsertData("@data_extension", 1, "Email Address", @email, "First Name", @firstName, "Last Name", @lastName)
```

Should be

```
UpsertData(@data_extension, 1, "Email Address", @email, "First Name", @firstName, "Last Name", @lastName)
```

Otherwise it is looking for a data extension named `@data_extension` not the value of the AMPscript variable named `@data_extension`

Also wanna remove those `<br>` tags in your script.